# What's the best way to check for Tcp disconnects?

Tags: c#

I'm making a chat program in C# using TCP and I'm having trouble handling disconnects. I need to make sure I can detect a disconnect whether it was manual or the client simply lost connection.

I've tried just closing the clients and streams, but they didn't throw exceptions in the server as they thought I did.

Also, is doing this necessary?

```
byte[] receive = new byte[10240];
int bytesReceived = 0;

try
{
    while (bytesReceived < receive.Length)
    {
        bytesReceived += Stream.Read(receive, 0, receive.Length);
    }
 }
```

I added this to make sure it gets all the bytes, but I'm not sure if I need to do this.

EDIT: changed it to this and it works. Thanks Jeroen Mostert for the help.

```
            byte[] receive = new byte[10240];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            try
            {
                bytesRead = Stream.Read(receive, 0, receive.Length);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                if (e.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(SocketException))
                {
                    SocketException socketExc = (SocketException)e.InnerException;

                    if (socketExc.SocketErrorCode == SocketError.Interrupted)
                    {
                        Running = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }

            if (bytesRead == 0)
            {
                Running = false;
                continue;
            }
```

Comment: Closing a connection cleanly will not produce exceptions; it will cause `.Read` calls to return with 0 bytes read. This should be used as a signal to stop receiving (so, obviously, your loop is not correct, and not necessary either -- `Stream.Read` will not return until it's read all you asked for, or there was no more to read; `Socket.Receive` is a different story). On the sender side, a disconnect will not be detected until the first attempt to send data over a connection that's no longer there. Most applications that want more instant detection use keepalive signals at regular intervals.

Comment: unrelated: `if (e.InnerException.GetType() == typeof(SocketException))
                {
                    SocketException socketExc =  (SocketException)e.InnerException;` = `if( e.InnerException is SocketException socketEx )` is much shorter and still pretty readable.